# Не могу зайти в mysql под другим пользователем Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Через терминал подключиться не могу: `mysql -u 'asd'@'localhost' -p`, однако через mysql connector все отлично работает, в чем дело?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `mysql -u asd@localhost -p`

Comment: @МихаилПроказин так я тоже самое в терминале ввел, попробовал ваш вариант без кавычек - тоже не работает

Comment: А если опустить `@localhost`, указав только имя пользователя?

Comment: @МихаилПроказин, капец, заработало, спасибо. Напишите это в ответ

Comment: не,ну решение гениальное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `mysql` имеет параметры `-u USER`, и `-h HOST`. Если хост не указан - по умолчанию подразумевается *localhost* или *127.0.0.1*.
При подключении имя пользователя получается примерно следующим образом `USER + "@" + HOST`.
Соответственно, если попытаться указать `-u user@host`, то получается:

```
USER = "user@host"
HOST = "localhost" (значение по умолчанию)
CONN = USER + "@" + HOST = "user@host@localhost"
```

Итого: имя сервера нужно указывать отдельным параметром `--host`, имя пользователя должно содержать **только** имя пользователя.